# Find all intersection points of complete graph

Tags: graphics, geometry

I want to create a picture like this:

[image]

This picture was found in [Regular Polygon Divisionby Diagonals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/notebooks/ComputationalGeometry/RegularPolygonDivisionbyDiagonals.nb).

But these codes are too old to run.

I think I can use `` Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections `` to find all the  intersection points.

```
lines=Line/@Tuples[CirclePoints[7],2];
pts=Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[lines]
Graphics[{{Thickness[0.005],lines},{Directive[Red,PointSize[0.02]],Point[pts]}}]
```

[image]

Looks it meets a bug. I need another way or try to fix it.

Comment: Indeed, there seems to be a problem with ``Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[]``. In the meantime: use `Subsets[]` instead of `Tuples[]`: `Line /@ Subsets[CirclePoints[7], {2}]`

Comment: Still have bug when $n$ is bigger, just try $n=8$ .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a brute-force solution that works in version 11.1, but not in the latest version:

```
lines = Line /@ Subsets[CirclePoints[7], {2}];
pts = DeleteCases[RegionIntersection @@@ Subsets[lines, {2}], _EmptyRegion];

Graphics[{lines, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], pts}]
```

[image: intersection points on the complete graph]

In 11.2, the corner points are missed:

[image: missing points]

because `RegionIntersection[]` apparently lost the ability to find intersections of two line segments sharing an endpoint in 11.2:

```
RegionIntersection[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}]]
   EmptyRegion[2]
```

where 11.1 would give the result `Point[{{0, 0}}]`.

Comment: Please report..

Comment: Just did.$\phantom{}$

Comment: For workaround, you can convert coords to numerical values. `lines = N[lines]`.