# Intersections of an array of Lines

Tags: computational-geometry, list-manipulation, intersection

I have an array of `Line` objects and I would like to compute all intersections in the set of lines using `RegionIntersection` on each possible pair. Is it possible somehow in Mathematica?

Comment: related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159818/9490

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks, it solved my problem indeed.